# Docusign Download documents from template

Tags: php, docusignapi

I'm looking for a way to download the documents from a template in Docusign.
I'm using the REST API in PHP.

CHALLENGE: I have a template that I use to send in the envelopes. I simply want to be able to pre-show those docs to someone before he signs and without needing to create an envelope for him.

SOLUTION: To download those docs of the template (and eventually attach them to email to potential signer). However I can't find any functionality for that.

I know you can download documents of an envelope [ https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/get-an-envelope-document-list ] but that is from an envelope that has been sent already whereas I want to download docs from the template.

Any help or alternative solution to the challenge is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. Figured it out. Answer is simple enough when you know....
Docusign regards a template as if it is just another envelope!

So by using [this method](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-rest-recipes/blob/master/download_documents/download_documents.php) or [this method](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/get-an-envelope-document-list) just substitute the envelopeID with your templateID and it should work.